# VB.net checking if active control is specific DGV

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to check if my Current DGV is a specific datagridview in my program named DgvDiameterData, so how do I preform this check?

I got this code which sets the active current DGV which works but the check doesnt and no idea how to get it to work

```
 Dim CurrentDGV As DataGridView = ActiveControl

    If CurrentDGV = DgvDiameterData Then 'the part after the = doesnt work

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Is` Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/is-operator).

From the link:

> The Is operator determines if two object references refer to the same object

So you need:

```
If CurrentDGV Is DgvDiameterData Then
```

This is less foolproof but you could also check the `Name` property.

```
If CurrentDGV.Name = DgvDiameterData.Name Then
```